# Rails: Making each choice in a form select field render relevant input in another form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Noob here so I apologize ahead of time for sounding like an amateur. I'm trying to code an e-commerce site. Customers will order posters from images uploaded to the site and get to choose the size of poster (h x w) they want depending on the dimensions of the original image. I have a form for creating a new order and one of the fields is a select field with the poster size options. When they select a size, I want a price to automatically update in a separate field in the form so they know before submitting the form what the price will be.

The strategy I've been trying is to add jQuery onclick code in the select field choices. Here's what I have for the form (just showing the first choice in the select field for brevity):

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
<div id="order_form">

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label(:size) %><br>
  <%= f.select(:size, [link_to("#{@image.dimensions['width']/120} * #{@image.dimensions['height']/120}", '#', :onclick => "showPrice('#{@image.dimensions['width']/120} * #{@image.dimensions['height']/120}'); return true;"), ... ]) %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label(:price) %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :price, :id => 'price' %>
 </div>

</div>
```

And in assets>javascripts>application.js my jQuery code is:

```
function showPrice(size) {
$("#price").html("$" + size * 0.08);
}
```

It's not working and I don’t know if what I’m trying to do won’t work or if I'm just doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you getting any errors in the javascript console? that might help us narrow down what is going wrong... Have you tried hard-coding the select-options to just dummy-values, to determine if it's your html/js that's breaking (as opposed to the railsy stuff)?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. In the browser the size select field shows 19 * 29">19 * 29 (for an image with dimensions 2280 x 3480) and nothing in the price field, where it should show 19 * 29 and $44.08 in the price field, so it seems like the problem is in trying to insert the jQuery in the select choices...

Comment: Like, literally: `19 * 29">19 * 29` ? that looks like it's getting confused between the text and value somehow - that can happen if there's a typo causing an improperly terminated string somewhere or similar. That's why the dummy-values test can help you... if it works with dummy-values hard-coded in, but doesn't work when you try to dynamically render the options... then you know it's something in how you're dynamically rendering them, rather than in the logic that works on the options once they're in place. :) (debugging techniques!)

Comment: It was my syntax causing the problem... I was trying to force the list of choices to be links which I don't think you can do... I found the correct syntax and fixed it and then rewrote the jQuery function... I'm gonna post the results below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with finally... I changed my goal a little, instead of trying to make it so when the user selects the size it will automatically update the price field I just made a separate paragraph (not a form field). Here's what it looks like:

```
<div id="order_form">

 <p id='price'><%= '$' + :size.to_int * 0.8 %></p>    
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label(:size) %><br>
  <%= f.select :size, ["#{@image.dimensions['width']/120} X #  {@image.dimensions['height']/120}", "#{@image.dimensions['width']/140} X #{@image.dimensions['height']/140}", "#{@image.dimensions['width']/160} X #{@image.dimensions['height']/160}", "#{@image.dimensions['width']/180} X #{@image.dimensions['height']/180}", "#{@image.dimensions['width']/200} X #{@image.dimensions['height']/200}", "#{@image.dimensions['width']/220} X #{@image.dimensions['height']/220}"], {}, :oninput => "showPrice(this)" %>
 </div>
</div>
```

and here's my jQuery function:

```
function showPrice(size) {
var Amt = $(size).val();
var arr = Amt.split(" ");
var newerAmt = Math.round( arr[0] * arr[2] * 0.8);
$("#price").html('Price: $' + newerAmt);
}
```

This works except it's not automatically showing the price when the page with the form loads with the default size... any advice on that would be great...

~~~~~~~~~

OK I finally figured that last part out. I referred to another thread on here and it led me to this solution so sorry for the resubmit but here it is:
To get JavaScript to recognize the ruby symbol :size I added this div in that same file:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "size_information", data: {size: @size} do %>
<% end %>
```

It isn't visible in the browser but it contains the data we need for JS.
Then in the JS function on that same page I referred to that data and then was able to use it as a variable:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
$(document).ready(function() {
var size = $('.size_information').data('size');
var arr = size.split(" ");
var newerAmt = Math.round( arr[0] * arr[2] * 0.8);
$("#price").html('Price: $' + newerAmt);
})
<% end %>
```

Comment: So to show it when the page loads, you need to run the function as the page loads like at the bottom of the page, have document on ready and just call the function there.

Comment: keep trying to do that and it's not working. Here's my code "<%= javascript_tag do %>
 $("document").ready(function() {
 showPrice(:size);
})

<% end %>"

Comment: `showPrice(:size)` shouldn't this be like, an actual size, not just a symbol called `size`? :)

Comment: No, it needs to be the symbol because it varies depending on what they press to get to this page. It's an attribute that gets sent when the page loads... I've gotten as far as getting the function to work if it is an actual size but not as a symbol. JavaScript isn't recognizing it so I need to somehow convert it to a js symbol...

Comment: when I say "an actual size" - that's what I mean... the actual size can be the thing that they passed in from what they pressed. A symbol is just not going to work, because it isn't a javascript thing. Your mission is to figure out how to turn the symbol dynamically into an actual size that the javascript can then use. If the ruby knows what this size is (eg it's in `params`) then you can interpolate eg `<%= javascript_tag do %> $("document").ready(function() { showPrice(<%= params[:size] %>); }) <% end %>` - or whatever it is that actually contains the size on your real code :)

Comment: I've been trying exactly that but it doesn't do anything... the page just loads without any errors. If i try it with escape_javascript or "j" inside the ruby tags it returns the error "undefined method 'gsub' for :size:Symbol". I've been researching how to pass ruby symbols to JavaScript so it can work with them but haven't quite gotten it to work yet... don't know if I'm missing something simple but I don't think so. Thanks for sticking with me on this, I know it must be getting tedious but I'm really trying... I appreciate it!

Comment: Can you please post (edit your question and put it there, not in comments where code-formatting is dreadful) the code that you are using when you get that error message - post every attempt you make. That way we can have a look at exactly what is going on :)

Comment: OK finally got it... refer to the edit I made on this Answer. I really thought it should work to use the ruby symbol in the JS function like you suggested so  it was a good learning experience to find that this didn't work... I kind of get the logic of why it doesn't. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```
$('select#size').change( function () {

  var amount = $('select#size').val();
  var newAmt = amount * 0.08
  $('#price').val('$' + newAmt);

})
```

Try breaking down the parts of the code to see which is working and which are not.

For example start with something simple like this

```
$('select#size').change(function () {  
  var amount = $('select#size').val();
  console.log(amount)
  //checking to see if .change function works
  //and if you are able to collect the value of 
  //whats inside 'select#size'
})
```

If this works then maybe you can consider doing the next line

```
var newAmt = amount * 0.08
console.log(newAmt)
```

If this works then next would be to try checking to see if you are successfully calling on the `#price` field.

```
var price = $('#price').val();
console.log(price)
```

So if thats working then maybe you can try placing values into `#price` first

```
$('#price').val('its working!')
```

If all of them are working, combining the whole code should work too. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that and it wasn't working but it led me to trying something similar:               'function showPrice(size) {
 var Amt = $(size).val();
 $("#price").html('Price: $' + Amt * 0.8);
}' which works if the input is an integer... the problem now is that it will not make the computation if the input is 16 * 25 or any other dimensions... I don't know why the multiplication isn't being completed... it just displays NaN :/

Comment: Okay i think it depends on what is the value being displayed in your `price` select? `NaN` means Not A Number. So there is a possibility that because of the way the value is stored in your `select` fields, JavaScript/jQuery is unable to process your method since they cant multiply the string by `0.8`. So that should be where your problem lies.